# Statistical testing for aggregated data

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am looking at the snack products that are advertised online over time. I have two variables, snack category (which includes 4 levels - chips, candy, drinks, meals) and time (3 levels - 2010, 2015, 2020). I have the average number of online ads seen by my sample for each year, by food category (i.e., aggregate data). I am wondering if there is a statistical test I could use test the differences between ads viewed by food category over time for aggregate data? Is it possible to use a z test of proportions or chi square?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to test? That they are from the same distribution? You can certainly test if they have teh same mean or not

Comment: I'm trying to test if there are statistically significant differences in the distribution of online ads by food category over time. (I'm very new to statistics so I'm not sure if this explains it any more clear)

Comment: You could use ANOVA if you were trying to test differences *in mean* between those distributions.

Comment: ok so if I used ANOVA, it would essentially be testing the differences in the mean of averages (since my data is actually the average amount of ads seen each year by food category)?